# removing outer nesting of python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which looks like as follows:

```
{u'start_time': u'1437056839370', u'playback': {u'duration': u'873041'}, u'end_time': u'1437058474763', u'id': u'61581a89c0804655f3a49b0df54468405d2bd78a'}
```

I would like to remove the playback attribute but I would like to keep the duration attribute to make the dictionary  be :

```
{u'start_time': u'1437056839370', u'duration': u'873041', u'end_time': u'1437058474763', u'id': u'61581a89c0804655f3a49b0df54468405d2bd78a'}
```

I am not sure how I can do that.

Comment: Is it always of the form `{... u'playback': {u'duration': 'something here'}, ...}` with those particular keys (`playback` and `duration`)? Or do you want to "de-nest" any possible keys?

Comment: `{('duration', d.get(k).get('duration')) if k=='playback' else (k, d.get(k)) for k in d}`.

Comment: It is always of that form {... u'playback': {u'duration': 'something here'}, ...} for the dictionary I am using.

Comment: In that case, any of the explicit forms below will work. `pop` is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Just do :

```
In [1]: d['duration']=d['playback']['duration']

In [2]: del d['playback']
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of the `pop` returning the popped item you can do the following:

```
d['duration'] = d.pop('playback')['duration']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to create a new `dict` from only the keys you need/want

```
dict_orig = {u'start_time': u'1437056839370', u'playback': {u'duration': u'873041'}, u'end_time': u'1437058474763', u'id': u'61581a89c0804655f3a49b0df54468405d2bd78a'}
dict_reduced = {k: dict_orig[k] for k in dict_orig.keys() & set(u'start_time', u'duration', u'end_time', u'id')}
```